# How to start Apache Traffic Server in MAC OS?

Tags: apache, apache-traffic-server

I have installed the Apache Traffic Server using the following instructions:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TS/Mac+OS+X

How I can start it and test?

Answer (score 1):

To start ATS: /usr/local/bin/trafficserver start

If you wish to just test/check if trafficserver is running then you could do http://localhost:8080 and you would get "Not Found on Accelerator" since your mapping rules(in remap.config) are not setup yet. Beyond this, depending on your usecase(reverse or forward proxying), you would have to do some configurations and only be able to test thereafter, your respective usecase.